# How to copy the working copy to another folder

Tags: python, git, rsync

I have a python package on my laptop. Sometimes, I need to run this package on my server, a more powerfull machine.

The python package is a git directory. But, when I'm running code on the server, this is often experimental, I don't want to commit anything to git.

How can I sync the code on my laptop and the code on the server?
Is there a way with git to copy my laptop working copy to the server?
Is rsync the only way?

I always need to copy the code on my laptop to the server, because the code has some build products that are dependent on the machine used.

I experimented with

```
$server: git clone path/to/laptop/package
$server: git fetch origin
```

but, it requires that I commit every changes on my laptop git directory.

Comment: What is wrong with rsync? As far as I know, git is designed to keep uncommited changes private.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with committing experimental changes and pushing them to the server's clone of the Git repo?

Comment: Right, just create an experimental branch for that.

Comment: (rsync:) I think git is faster, so it would be best if the clone could fetch the working copy. (experimental branch:) I'm trying to automote the update to the server, so using an experimental branch is more work. Before proceeding in this way, I was hoping there is a magic git command for this.

Comment: You want to commit.  As recommended, create a branch, and commit to it.  On server just checkout the branch.  If you are wanting to use git, then trying to hide things from git doesn't make sense.  It will help you recover from your mishaps

Comment: Yes, git is definitely faster if your repository is big. What exactly do you want to automate? You can use a script to commit all your changes to the experimental branch and push that. Actually, I see nothing you could not automate.

Comment: I see, I will proceed as recommeded using an experimental branch. I'm clearer on how the process would go, and yes, it is automatable: laptop_create_experimental_branch  ;  laptop_commit_to_experimental_branch  ;   server_fetch_experimental_branch   ;   server_run_code   ;  finish.